# Explanatory dictionaries in machine-readable format

Tags: json, xml, csv, dictionary

Please tell me where I can get explanatory dictionaries for Spanish, Portuguese, Italian, French, German in CSV (or any other machine-readable) format? API access to such dictionaries is also possible (but not desirable)

Wikidictionary is not suitable. It has no definitions for too many words.